# c++ accurate timer time.h boost::posix_time

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am trying to create a timer to profile some functions. For example,

```
#include <date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime t1, t2;
t1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
t2 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

std::cout << to_simple_string(t1) << std::endl;
std::cout << to_simple_string(t2) << std::endl;
```

The output I get is this,

```
2012-Mar-04 08:21:24.760019
2012-Mar-04 08:21:25.760577
```

The actual time elapsed is 1 second and 558 micro second, is there anyway that I can improve this accuracy to say under 1 microsecond?

I also tried something like this, with linker -lrt.

```
#include <time.h>
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timer_start);
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
clock_gettime(1CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timer_end);
```

But the compiler returns a semantic error for CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID. The error message is as follow.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID' could not be resolved _OVERVIEW.cpp   /FUTETP/BACKEND line 32 Semantic Error
```

Comment: Could you please show how you're compiling? (Full compiler command line) And what OS are you using?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the it's the timer call that is inaccurate. There's probably a much larger inaccuracy in the `sleep` call.

Comment: @Mat, I am using eclipse on Fedora 15, gnu gcc 4.6.

Comment: @mat, make all 
Building file: ../BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x `wx-config --static=no --cxxflags` -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/boost -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.d" -MT"BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.d" -o "BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.o" "../BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.cpp"
Finished building: ../BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.cpp

Comment: Linker. Building target: FUTETP
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib `wx-config --static=no --libs` -Wl,--rpath,/usr/local/lib/ -o "FUTETP"  ./src/FUTETP.o  ./GUI/MyFrame.o ./GUI/MyPanelInst.o ./GUI/MyPanelOverview.o ./GUI/MyPanelSymbol.o ./GUI/MyTextCtrl.o ./GUI/MyToggleButton.o ./GUI/_BASE_GUI.o  ./BACKEND/MarketDataInterface.o ./BACKEND/OrderInterface.o ./BACKEND/_BASE.o ./BACKEND/_INSTRUMENT.o ./BACKEND/_OVERVIEW.o ./BACKEND/_SYMBOL.o   -lrt -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time
Finished building target: FUTETP

Comment: Can't repro the build failure with GCC 4.6.2/4.7.smthing/4.5.3 (after removing the obvious typo in the second `clock_gettime` call anyway).

Comment: @Mat, thank you for testing the code. I think the problem is that the compiler is unable to recognize CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID.

Comment: @2607 I have the same semantic error, although the program seems working. Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind two things:

1. `sleep()` and other time-sensitive commands could be inaccurate for several reasons (system load, etc.).  You will never get within 1 microsecond accuracy.  500 microseconds isn't too bad for timing `sleep()`
2. If your system time is controlled by NTP, etc. and the clock is changed during your timing operation, you **will** see this.  If the time is rolled back, it is possible to obtain a negative (or large unsigned number).

By the way, I'm unsure of what method Boost is using to get the time, but consider `gettimeofday(2)` from `sys/time.h` (or newer `clock_gettime()` from `time.h`).  It returns the time since midnight Jan 1, 1970.  Record the time before and after and subtract.  Here's an example of `gettimeofday()`.

```
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned int
timeDif(
    struct timeval *before,
    struct timeval *after)
{
    return ((after->tv_sec * 1000000 + after->tv_usec) - 
        (before->tv_sec * 1000000 + before->tv_usec));
}

int
main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[]) {
    struct timeval before, after;

    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    gettimeofday(&after, NULL);

    printf("Elapsed time: %u microseconds\n", timeDif(&before, &after));

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I didn't know it is difficult to get a high accuracy on timing functions such as sleep(). I used boost::posix_time before and got an accuracy error around 500msec, that's why I switched to time.h.